# ndarray take power element by element

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

In Rust, `(3.0).powf(4.0)` will take the power of 3^4. `ndarray` supports many operators, like `array1 + array2`. How do you take the elementwise power?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function to apply anything you like per cell. For example, with powf:

```rust
use ndarray;

fn main() {
    let arr = ndarray::array![[1, 2], [3, 4], [6, 7]];
    println!("{:?}", arr);
    let arr = arr.map(|&item| (item as f32).powf(4.0));
    println!("{:?}", arr);
}
```